# COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am trying to setup a s3 bucket and github account to create a pipeline in aws codepipeline service. I am getting an error I can't seem to find. It seems to be related to the NPM Install command, but not sure why. Can someone help please?

COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: npm i. Reason: exit status 1

BuildSpec:

```
version: 0.2

env:
    variables:
        CACHE_CONTROL: "86400"
        S3_BUCKET: "{{s3_bucket_url}}"
        BUILD_FOLDER: "dist"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 16
    commands:
        - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
        - npm install
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
  build:
    commands:
        - echo Build started 
        - ng build
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist*'
    discard-paths: yes
```